# Command works at the file path, but won't work from root

Tags: python-3.x

I'm still a newbie at bash programming, but trying to run a program with little script. Reducing the problem to the error message, I have

```
cd /full/path/to/program
python3 -m krop
```

that is the command working when the actual folder is the /full/path/to/program

but if I run the same from root it doesn't work.

```
cd /another/path
python3 -m /full/path/to/program/krop
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for '/full/path/to/program/krop' 
(ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'krop-0')
```

I tried lot of variants, but always the same output with errors. I do not have a clue of why the library "python3" adds the "-0" at the end of the name of the file.

What should I put to run the program from root?

Comment: what do you see when you run `cat /full/path/to/program/krop`?

Comment: python adds the current working directory to `sys.path`; that is where the module `krop-0` seems to live. so if you start your program from a different directory you need to make sure `sys.path` is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`python -m` command expects a module name, similarly to the syntax you would `import` in a python program. So if your modules lies in `./directory` and `directory` is a valid python module, you can do `python -m directory.krop`

You can't however index python modules from file system root. You have either to make your bash script run it in the good directory so you make a local import; or you have to package and install your module system-wide to make a global import that would be invoked with `python -m krop` from anywhere.

More information on packaging and installing modules: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!,

It was a matter of managing the python import paths, as @hiroprotagonist replied. The list that contains all of directories python will use to search for modules, is available in a variable named sys.path.
So, if somebody wants to run a program (a 'library module as a script', according to python help) through python's command, from a directory different from the 'pwd' one, should write in the command line:

```
export PYTHONPATH='/full/path/to/program/'
python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
python3 -m krop
```

The second line is actually to print on screen, but the first one is the only necessary (export PYTHONPATH).

Thank you for the keywords and help!

Ps. May be should be edited the question title to "problem with a python command to run a program from command line on linux" or something like that.

Reference: python --help :)